# Datatype date not sortable when set to date

Tags: jquery, sorting, date, datatable

```
var eventsTable = $("#eventsTable").DataTable({
    "ajax": '',
    "aaSorting": [0, "desc"],
    "bSortable": true,
    "aoColumnDefs": [{"sType": "date", "aTargets":[0]}],
    "aoColumns": [
   { "data": "DateModified"},
   { "data": "Type"},
   { "data": "UserName" },
   { "data": "Description" },
   { "data": "Priority" }
    ]
});
```

The code above is the bit of code that initializes the datatable to be displayed on my page. The initial sorting when the datatable is meant to display by date descending (newest entry first). This works perfectly with this bit of code.

However, when i click on the arrow thats attached to Date to sort the column in different directions, nothing happens. The data stays the same. If i try to sort any other columns using the datatable it works. Only doesn't work when the data type is set to date. When i remove date, it allows the Date column to sort, but the sorting is incorrect.

Is there something that can be done about the datatable so that it allows me to keep an sType: date, and still be able to sort the table using the arrows on the datatable when needed.

This is the datatable on initial load displaying by date descending:

[image]

This one is when i have tried to sort by ascending by clicking the arrow. Nothing has changed but the arrow location:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since date sorting varies by date format, and date format varies by location, Datatables introduced a [date sorting plugin](http://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18).

There is also a working demo on that page.